# Check for nil values in Dictionary - Swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have converted a XML into a Dictionary and I would like to check first if any of the values is nil.

Is there any alternative to this ugly code (the Dictionary contains 30 key-value pairs):

```
if (xmlDict["key1" != nil && xmlDict["key2" != nil && .... && xmlDict["key30" != nil) {
     //Do something with these values
} else {
     //Do not do anything at all with this dictionary
}
```

**[Update]**
The dictionary has this format (mixed value types):

```
let futuramaDict = NSArray(contentsOf: xmlFile!) as? [NSDictionary]

futuramaDict {
     "Cartoon" : "Futurama"
     "Length" : 120
     "MainCharacter" : "Philip J. Fry"
     "ClosestFriends" : ["Bender","Leela","Zoidberg"]
     }
```

I left the other key-value pairs so I don't fill the thread with irrelevant content

Comment: In view of the various answers (which may or may not work in your case) it would be helpful to show how *exactly* your directionary is defined and filled.

Comment: Updated question with a Dictionary example

Answer (score 3):

You can check with one line

```
xml.values.filter({ $0 == nil }).isEmpty
```

Here's the complete snippet

```
let xml: [String: String?] = [
    "key1" : "Value1",
    "key2" : "Value2",
    "key3" : nil,
    "key4" : "Value4"
]

if xml.values.filter({ $0 == nil }).isEmpty
{
    print("Plenty of values")
}
else
{
    print("nil :(")
}
```

Comment: When parsing xml to dictionary you will never get optional values. Optional values in a Swift dictionary are silly anyway (in Objective-C they are even forbidden). A `nil` value when subscribing the dictionary with a key indicates *key is missing*.

Comment: using filter is suboptimal since it has to go through every element even if the first one it finds matches the condition.

Comment: Hi @vadian Reading the question I assume that there are some tratement over XML to Dictionary process that puts nil values in some keys.

Comment: Hi @marosoaie If we were talkinga bout long time running process that read billions of xml documents with thousands of key-values I agree with you, but if the purpouse it's read only one XML the process time and response time providen by filter it's ok. In my opinion, of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

A more "swifty" way:

```
for (key, val) in xmlDict where val == nil {
    print("Found a nil value for this key: \(key)")
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `val == nil` will never evaluate to `true` after converting xml directly to dictionary.

Comment: This will not enumerate keys which are not present in the dictionary.

Comment: For whom edited my question in this way `for (key, val) in xmlDict, val == nil`, it doesn't work. Please be sure when you edit the code that is still working, where clause is valid in swift 3

Comment: @MartinR could you elaborate your comment, I think I didn't get it :(

Comment: `xmlDict["key1"]` returns `nil` if the dictionary does not contain a value for the key "key1". In that case, enumerating the dictionary will not return a pair `("key1", nil)`.

Comment: @vadian probably but I guess it depends on how the dictionary is defined and we have no clue about it. I'm imagining something like [String:Any?]. did I get your comment correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This code should achieve what you want:

```
var values = [Any]()

for index in 1 ... 30 {

    let key = "key\(index)" // Generates "key1" through "key30"

    guard let value = xmlDict[key] else {
        values.removeAll()
        break // Abort loop
    }

    values.append(values)
}

// Next: Process contents of array 'values' 
// (will be empty if any key was absent)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and short solution:

```
if xmlDict.values.contains(where: {$0 == nil}) {
    print("Dict contains at least one nil value")
}
```

In the case when you have a predefined set of keys you want to look for:

```
let keysToLookFor = ["k1", "k2", "k3", "k4"]
if keysToLookFor.contains(where: {xmlDict[$0] == nil}) {
    print("Dict contains at least one nil value")
}
```

A sample dict for testing:

```
let xmlDict: [String: Any?] = ["k1": 22, "k2": Int(2), "k3": nil]
```

Comment: This will not find values for keys which are not present in the dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR can you please explain what you mean by keys which are not present?

Comment: @Eendje a dict can contain keys with a nil value (`["key": nil]` is a valid dict)

Comment: @Eendje that's not true. The code is there, you can try it.

Comment: You're right, I'm deleting my comments as it's not helping the answer and I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
let hasAnyKeyNil = dic.keys.contains(where: { dic[$0]! == nil })
```